# Using expect to write a bash script

Tags: awk, expect

I am trying to write a bash script using expect.  This bash script will reside on a remote server, to be executed at a later date/time. I am using expect to read in a large data file, perform some processing on it, and writing out the bash script with appropriate values.  To do I this, I set up variable that will hold the value of the bash script:

```
set awk_cmd "awk '\{print \\\$3\}'"
if {$reboot==$reboot_N} {
set command5 "echo '#!/bin/bash\n\ndeclare -i last_reboot=\$(w | grep up | grep days | ${awk_cmd})\n\nif (( \$last_reboot !< 8 )); then\necho \"Your ..."' > /root/script.sh
```

I have obviously redacted a good portion of the echo command.  However, the error I'm getting is in the ${awk_cmd} portion.  awk uses the format "awk '{print $3}'".

However, I cannot get the single quotes to print to the bash script.  The above prints out {print $3} without the quotes, and all attempts at escaping the single quotes in the awk command have failed.

Notice that I am already using double quotes and single quotes in this.  Everything in my command works EXCEPT the awk command.

What am I missing?

EDIT:  To make it a bit simpler (I hope), I am trying to pass a literal single quote inside a single-quoted string

Comment: This would probably be easier if you could scp the script

Answer (score 0):

I think I've figured it out.

```
set command5 "echo '#!/bin/bash\n\ndeclare -i last_reboot=\$(w | grep up | grep days | awk '\\\''\{print \$3\}'\\\'')\n\nif....." > script.sh
```

The above produces the following:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

declare -i last_reboot=$(w | grep up | grep days | awk '{print $3}')

if (( $last_reboot >= 7 )); then
echo "Your ..."
```

I found the answer [here](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/problem-escaping-single-quote-when-using-usr-bin-expect-c-4175600628/). I just had not figured out the correct escape sequence.